# Не работает инкремент

Tags: java, android, инкремент

Я новичок,поэтому не кидайте сразу кирпичами,а лучше посоветуйте почитать годную литературу

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private int money;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            savedInstanceState.getInt("money", money);
        }
        Money();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("money", money);
    }

    public void onMon(View v) {
        money++;
    }

    public void Money () {
        final TextView moneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_view);
        int n = money;
        String money = String.format("%08d%n", n);
        moneyView.setText(money);
    }
}
```

Comment: int money не иницилизирован. `public void onMon(View v)` не нуждается в рагументах. и название метода не соответствющее

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, это функция-обработчик нажатия кнопки. Там по-любому она принимает View.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в данном случае инициализировать money не обязательно, jvm неявно инициализирует это поле нулем.

Comment: @КириллМалышев скажите что конкретно не работает, из приложенного кода мало что понятно. Сразу могу сказать только что в джаве не принято писать название метода с большой буквы (метод Money() в вашем примере). И не очень хорошо то, что не понятно что за обработчик onMon() и что он должен делать(вызываться каждый понедельник? тогда можно дать более говорящее имя методу)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `savedInstanceState.getInt` возвращает значение по ключу, а второй аргумент служит для значения по-умолчанию (значение по-умолчанию будет возвращено в том случае, когда для ключа "money" нет никакого значения). У вас в коде `savedInstanceState.getInt` возвращает значение в пустоту, поэтому изменим эту часть кода на `money = savedInstanceState.getInt("money", 0);`.

Изменим название метода `Money()` на `money()`, так как в Java не принято называть методы с большой буквы.

Код в методе `money()` можно переписать и избавиться от `int n` и `String money`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private int money;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            money = savedInstanceState.getInt("money", 0);
        }
        money();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("money", money);
    }

    public void onMon(View v) {
        money++;
    }

    public void money () {
        TextView moneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money_view);
        moneyView.setText(String.format("%08d%n", money));
    }
}
```

Насчет литературы, я бы порекомендовал прочитать эту книгу - "Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс, Android. Программирование для профессионалов, **2-е издание**"

Comment: Дай вам бог здоровья счастья,скорости интернета в 1 гиг,и иммунитет от шифровальщиков!